# Automatically log a user on to Google

Tags: authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to log a user into Google Calendar without  the user having to enter their name and password. I have successfully set up OATH and with this I can from a PHP script manipulate their calendar.  But what I need to do is run a script and somehow then create a link for the user to click on to gain access.

Please see step 1 to Step 5 in the sample php copde below. This is basicaly the simple.php code in the calendar sample.

I may misunderstand the workflow but it is this.
1) Create Auth URL
2) Get a code and call myself back with a token
3) Set the token
4) Use this token to access the calendar
5) Use the token to give access to the calendar -- this is the part that does not work

/ SAMPLE PHP CODE ******************/

```
require_once '../phplibs/gApi/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../phplibs/gApi/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");

 $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 $client->setRedirectUri(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // The redirect is this same script
 $client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  //Step 2
  //I have been called back with the code
  // so use this to create a token
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  // Step 3
  // I have been called back by the redirect in step 2
  // but now with an access token
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

  //Step 4
  // My token exists so now I can work on the users calanders
  // I dont want to do this but it does work so proves the auth worked ok
    $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
   //print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";

   //Not sure why this happens again as we have a token
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

   // Step 5
   // This is really want I want to do, I want to open the users calendar in a iframe or full page
   // However if the user is not logged in they get redirected to the Google login page
   // I was expecting that as the token was set this should work.


   header('Location: https://www.google.com/calendar/render');
  // echo(' <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=calendar%40wokingham-theatre.org.uk&ctz=Europe/London" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');



} else {
  //Step 1  
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'> Connect to the Google calendar without me having to enter my name and password </a>";
```

Comment: I'm missing something.   If you have PHP code that can manipulate the calendar, why can’t you link to this code?

Comment: Tim, thanks for looking I have hopefully clarified the question. It's very possible I am missing the point completey